# adding auto config formatting the different folders

Tags: husky, git-husky

I have a sample web project which has client and server, so before commit any files I have added husky to make the formatting changes, when I add it as script it works but when I do git add . and git commit its showing as

```
No staged files match any configured task.
```

What am I doing wrong here.

client
package.json

```
 "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
  }
```

server
package.json

```
   "husky": {
        "hooks": {
          "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
      },
      "lint-staged": {
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
          "prettier --write"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "husky": "^4.3.8",
        "lint-staged": "^12.3.1",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
      }
```

What am I doing here wrong, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check first if, as in [`typicode/husky` issue 767](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/767), a `npm rebuild` is needed.

Double-check also the [installation process](https://github.com/typicode/husky) to see if a simple npm test, for instance, would work (`npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm test"`)

Comment: I have checked the npm rebuild but that didn't done anything, same issue. So what I done added some changes, then npm rebuild then git add . , then git commit but still same No staged files match any configured task.

Comment: Is it because of client and server folder my project structure is application inside two folders client (react) and server (node js)

Comment: @dev Possible. I would start from a simper project, just to test if the commit hook works there, before adding back elements of your current project structure.

Comment: @VonC I feel like there is no need for this comment, and I'm sorry if so but I'm trying to pass you in the weekly leaderboard :P

Comment: @Sarout No problem. Passing me in any leaderboard is good for the community: more high quality answers benefit everyone.

Comment: yeah, I've liked helping others in this community in my week off, but passing you in all-time's leaderboard is like trying to cut the earth 8 pieces...